# arcpy.management.DeleteField working in Pro notebook but not online hosted notebook

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

I'm trying to take some models in ArcGIS Pro that I've built, and translate them into a AGOL Advanced notebook. Originally I was building the notebook in Pro for testing. However I just tried it in the online environment and am not having any success.

Here's the code (works in an ArcGIS Pro Notebook.)

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS("home")
import arcpy
line_url = ("https://services8.arcgis.com/kiN57DOJrIhpvBby/arcgis/rest/services/<LineLayer>/FeatureServer/98")
table_url = ("https://services8.arcgis.com/kiN57DOJrIhpvBby/arcgis/rest/services/<TableForJoin>/FeatureServer/0")
arcpy.management.DeleteField(in_table=line_url, drop_field=["Freight", "Price_Per_Foot", "Price_Per_Unit", "Type", "Description" ])[0]

arcpy.management.JoinField(
    in_data=line_url,
    in_field="Lock",
    join_table=table_url,
    join_field="Key_",
    fields="Description;Price_Per_Foot;Price_Per_Unit;Freight",
    fm_option="NOT_USE_FM",
    field_mapping=None
)
```

And the error returned

```
Input In [110], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #Drop Fields
----> 2 arcpy.management.DeleteField(
      3     in_table=line_url,
      4     drop_field="Lock;Description;Price_Per_Foot;Price_Per_Unit;Freight",
      5     method="DELETE_FIELDS"
      6 )
      8 arcpy.management.JoinField(
      9     in_data=line_url,
     10     in_field="Lock",
   (...)
     15     field_mapping=None
     16 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcpy/management.py:6025, in DeleteField(in_table, drop_field, method)
   6023     return retval
   6024 except Exception as e:
-> 6025     raise e

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcpy/management.py:6022, in DeleteField(in_table, drop_field, method)
   6020 from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
   6021 try:
-> 6022     retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.DeleteField_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table, drop_field, method), True)))
   6023     return retval
   6024 except Exception as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcpy/geoprocessing/_base.py:512, in Geoprocessor.__getattr__.<locals>.<lambda>(*args)
    510 val = getattr(self._gp, attr)
    511 if callable(val):
--> 512     return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    513 else:
    514     return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(val)

ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Table: Dataset https://services8.arcgis.com/kiN57DOJrIhpvBby/arcgis/rest/services/<LineLayer>/FeatureServer/98 does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (DeleteField).
```

So my end goal here is to have a table hosted in AGOL that when updated, will update prices in hosted Feature Layers. Then on to field calculates to get price of line based on (feet*price per foot).

I'm deleting fields before joining because if I don't delete, the join just continually adds more sequential fields that do not fit in with the field calculation done later in the script (at least that's how it worked in model builder).

I've also tried gis.content.get, and converting to the FeatureLayer module in this script, and get a different error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [111], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #arcpy.management.DeleteField(in_table=lineFeature, drop_field=["Freight", "Price_Per_Foot", "Price_Per_Unit", "Type", "Description"])[0]
----> 2 arcpy.management.DeleteField(
      3     in_table=FuturePipe,
      4     drop_field="Lock;Description;Price_Per_Foot;Price_Per_Unit;Freight",
      5     method="DELETE_FIELDS"
      6 )
      8 arcpy.management.JoinField(
      9     in_data=lineFeature,
     10     in_field="Lock",
   (...)
     15     field_mapping=None
     16 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcpy/management.py:6025, in DeleteField(in_table, drop_field, method)
   6023     return retval
   6024 except Exception as e:
-> 6025     raise e

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcpy/management.py:6022, in DeleteField(in_table, drop_field, method)
   6020 from arcpy.arcobjects.arcobjectconversion import convertArcObjectToPythonObject
   6021 try:
-> 6022     retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.DeleteField_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table, drop_field, method), True)))
   6023     return retval
   6024 except Exception as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcpy/geoprocessing/_base.py:512, in Geoprocessor.__getattr__.<locals>.<lambda>(*args)
    510 val = getattr(self._gp, attr)
    511 if callable(val):
--> 512     return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
    513 else:
    514     return convertArcObjectToPythonObject(val)

RuntimeError: Object: Error in executing tool
```

Is there a better way to do this? How can I get the delete then join function working correctly?